# Internal CSS not working with Java Script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have given background color an width to div ids f1,f2,f3,f4 in style tag that is in head (internal CSS) but they wont show when i run the code. If i apply inline CSS then it works.I have filtered the code this is not a complete code but will help in solving my problem.

```js
function Coordinates() {
  var x;
  var y;
  x = document.getElementById("mynumber3").value;
  y = document.getElementById("mynumber4").value;
  if (x > 0 && y > 0) {
    document.getElementById("f1").innerHTML = "(" + x + "," + y + ")";
  } else if (x < 0 && y > 0) {
    document.getElementById("f2").innerHTML = "(" + x + "," + y + ")";
  }
}
```

```css
# f1 {
  background-color: #CCC;
  width: 12%;
  height: 12%;
  position: fixed
}

# f2 {
  background-color: #CCC;
  width: 12%;
  height: 12%;
}

# f3 {
  background-color: #CCC;
  width: 12%;
  height: 12%;
}

# f4 {
  background-color: #CCC;
  width: 12%;
  height: 12%;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="four">
    <h1>Quadrant</h1>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td><label>Enter First Number</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="mynumber3"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><label>Enter Second Number</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="mynumber4"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <button onclick="Coordinates()">Go</button>
    <div id="f1"></div>
    <div id="f2"></div>
    <div id="f3"></div>
    <div id="f4"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Uh, `# f4` and the like are not valid css selectors...  Take out the space.  It should be `#f4`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`# f1`, `# f2`, `# f3`, and `# f4` are not valid CSS selectors. Remove the unncecessary space and it will work (it should be `#f1`, `#f2`, `#f3`, and `#f4`).

```js
function Coordinates() {
  var x;
  var y;
  x = document.getElementById("mynumber3").value;
  y = document.getElementById("mynumber4").value;
  if (x > 0 && y > 0) {
    document.getElementById("f1").innerHTML = "(" + x + "," + y + ")";
  } else if (x < 0 && y > 0) {
    document.getElementById("f2").innerHTML = "(" + x + "," + y + ")";
  }
}
```

```css
#f1 {
  background-color: #CCC;
  width: 12%;
  height: 12%;
  position: fixed
}

#f2 {
  background-color: #CCC;
  width: 12%;
  height: 12%;
}

#f3 {
  background-color: #CCC;
  width: 12%;
  height: 12%;
}

#f4 {
  background-color: #CCC;
  width: 12%;
  height: 12%;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="four">
    <h1>Quadrant</h1>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td><label>Enter First Number</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="mynumber3"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><label>Enter Second Number</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="mynumber4"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <button onclick="Coordinates()">Go</button>
    <div id="f1"></div>
    <div id="f2"></div>
    <div id="f3"></div>
    <div id="f4"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

The divs with the `id`s of `f2`, `f3`, and `f4` should be styled with a class instead of an `id` as their CSS is exactly the same (only the `div` with the `id` `f1` is slightly different).

```js
function Coordinates() {
  var x;
  var y;
  x = document.getElementById("mynumber3").value;
  y = document.getElementById("mynumber4").value;
  if (x > 0 && y > 0) {
    document.getElementById("f1").innerHTML = "(" + x + "," + y + ")";
  } else if (x < 0 && y > 0) {
    document.getElementById("f2").innerHTML = "(" + x + "," + y + ")";
  }
}
```

```css
#f1 {
  background-color: #CCC;
  width: 12%;
  height: 12%;
  position: fixed
}

.f {
  background-color: #CCC;
  width: 12%;
  height: 12%;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="four">
    <h1>Quadrant</h1>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td><label>Enter First Number</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="mynumber3"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><label>Enter Second Number</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="mynumber4"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <button onclick="Coordinates()">Go</button>
    <div id="f1"></div>
    <div class="f" id="f2"></div>
    <div class="f"></div>
    <div class="f"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```